# Bumblebee optirun CrossOver games

Tags: 12.04, wine, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, crossover

I've been trying to play a Ragnarok Online private server with wine but this specifically server gets stuck in a faded login screen, with sound.

So I installed CrossOver and it runs nice! But I need to run optirun in order to use my nvidia geforce 630M instead of intel ivybridge but I just can't find how to insert this command on CrossOver applications.

Thanks!

Ubuntu 12.04, CrossOver 13.1, LimitRO (limit-ro.net)

Comment: **"I just can't find how to insert "this" command"**. Which command?

Comment: @PatilAditya "optirun"

Without CrossOver it would be like: optirun wine Launcher.exe -c :8

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but since this question comes up on google, I will explain how I can use my Geforce GT 635M with crossover:

1) Find out how the windows program is launched;
check /home//desktop/Some App.desktop for the Exec Line

2a) prepend primusrun (or optirun)

OR

2b) the Exec line tells to execute a script somewhere in .cxoffice/.../.lnk; edit that script and prepend primusrun (or optirun) to the command in the script